# In German, how would you say “laid to rest” or “final resting place”?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

I want to say for example,

> Jim Morrison, whose final resting place is Paris, …

I could say something like the following:

> Jim Morrison, who is buried in Paris, …

but “final resting place” sounds better.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=final+resting+place – http://dict.leo.org/#/search=resting-place&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on – http://de.pons.com/übersetzung?q=resting-place&l=deen&in=&lf=en

Answer (score 13):

*Die letzte Ruhestätte* is a popular choice.

On a somewhat elevated language level one would write:

> Jim Morrison fand seine letzte Ruhestätte auf dem Père Lachaise in Paris.

Answer (score 6):

And for "laid to rest" a nice way of saying that in German would be "zu Grabe getragen" or "zur letzten Ruhe geleitet / gebettet"

> Jim Morrison wurde in Paris zu Grabe getragen.
>
> Jim Morrison wurde in Paris zur letzten Ruhe geleitet / gebettet.

Comment: Oder auch "zur letzten Ruhe gebettet."

Comment: Yes that's true. I will add that.

Answer (score 1):

A bit less formal would be "begraben liegen" (to lie buried), "Jim Morrison liegt in Paris begraben". BTW, we tend to be more precise about the resting place if we can, often naming the cemetery and not just the town or country.